# Former moderators still shown on stackexchange.com

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

The section of the main Stack Exchange page that displays all the many sites in expandable thumbnails has the former moderators for Code Review.

[image: picture of expanded codereview]

I don't know how many other sites display incorrect moderator teams as I have not been very active on the other sites but I assume there may be others as well.

Comment: For anyone else who is curious, this is talking about https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those aren't (necessarily) moderators, just high-rep users.

I checked a few sites where I know offhand who the moderators are and most of the users who show up have never been moderators, they're the all-time highest-rep users on the sites.

Checking a few more sites, that seems to be the pattern - the highest-rep users are shown.  If some of them happen to be former moderators, that could explain your misunderstanding.

Comment: @bruglesco It shows the top 5 users by reputation, whether they are (ex) moderators or not. So it has nothing to do with moderators.